# flutter type error while parsing json data using json serialisable

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to parse data from a json. I think this image will help you to understand the problem.

[image]

I am getting 
`Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type '(dynamic) => MainRank' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')`

If you hover over the body, you will see the black pop up with the data. ranks is a list and there are two extra properties there as well.

My `MainRank` class is like this

```
class MainRank{
  String divisionName;
  String tournamentName;

  final  List<Ranks> ranks; 

  MainRank(this.divisionName, this.tournamentName, this.ranks);
  factory MainRank.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
     _$MainRankFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MainRankToJson(this);
}
```

Please help me with a little bit explanation how it works in dart. I am from php/js background so data types seems giving me hard time :) Thank you,

**EDIT**
Response from my api is

```
{
  ranks: [....],
  divisionName: "Division 2",
  tournamentName: "Season 4"
}
```

And code I am using to parse the json is

```
Future _getData() async{
var res = await CallApi().getData('standings/${widget.id}');
final body = json.decode(res.body);
// final matches = body['matches'];
var data;

if(body!=null){
   data = body.map((el) => MainRank.fromJson(el));
}
print(data);
 return null;
}
```

Comment: what is the json response from your webservice ?

Comment: Edited the question. Please see :) Thank you

Comment: what is the line of your error?

Comment: This is the line `data = body.map((el) => MainRank.fromJson(el));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the `MainRank` from your json data, so :

Change this :

```
 var data;

 if(body!=null){
    data = body.map((el) => MainRank.fromJson(el));
 }
```

To this:

```
MainRank data;

if(body!=null){
    data = MainRank.fromJson(body);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was used to parsing list so I had to use map. :) now it all works nicely!